# Explicit wait not working, Thread.sleep works

Tags: java, selenium

Trying to use explicit wait but it is not working. If Thread.sleep is added it works perfectly fine. Selenium WebDriver 3 and Firefox 55. Below is the code.
Code

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement w1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='formdesigner']"));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(w1));
driver.findElement((By.xpath("//*[@id='formdesigner']"))).click();
```

Have also tried Actions class move to element and then click but same problem. Checked for element displayed, it is displayed but still no click happening and no error displayed. Please help me to get the solution for this. Can't keep on using Thread.sleep as it is not correct to do so.

HTML code:

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mrQ4.png)

```
<div class="col-sm-6 full-height">
    <div id="formdesigner" class="row full-height">
        <div class="col-sm-12 tile-name">FORM DESIGNER</div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 tile-image">
            <div class="link-img"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share the relevant `HTML` please.

Comment: I'm new to Selenium, can you let me know how to provide relevant HTML

Comment: The same way you came to know about the `xpath` of the element as `"//*[@id='formdesigner']"`. Copy some more tags from the `HTML DOM` (up/down) around the element and paste within your Question area.

Comment: Thanks, I have added image. Let me know if more details are required

Comment: Sharing an image of the `HTML` is not a best practice on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) Try adding relevant formatted `HTML` as text.

Comment: @Vihu Why you feel thread.sleep is not good practice ? and how much sleep you are using ?

Comment: @DebanjanB HTML code <div class="col-sm-6 full-height">
 <div id="formdesigner" class="row full-height">
  <div class="col-sm-12 tile-name">FORM DESIGNER</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 tile-image">
   <div class="link-img"/>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: @Sagar007.. I feel it is not good for application which i'm automating since it is web application which fetches data from DB and it has happened like when connection is slow when data is more to load, I have to go and increase the thread.sleep period which was actually working before. And also thread.sleep is not based on any condition so better to have explicit wait which is based on condition

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement w1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='formdesigner']"));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(w1));
driver.findElement((By.xpath("//*[@id='formdesigner']"))).click();
```

Try this code block :

```
WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement w2 = wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.xpath("//div[@id='formdesigner']/div[@class='col-sm-12 tile-name']"))));
w2.click();
```

Comment: Tried, but still not working. If I put Thread.sleep it will work fine.

Comment: Try updated answer/code. `Thread.sleep()` is not a good practice.

Comment: Few more details to add here, after clicking on "Form Designer" link, application loads new page. Is this the reason for click not working. Thing is no error is thrown so don't know what is happening.

Comment: @Vihu It is a div tag. How can it open a new window?

Comment: It is not opening new window, it is opening new page.

Comment: @Vihu It won't open a new window, it's not within an a tag.

Comment: It is opening new page but through click event of Java script which is hiding old one and getting replaced by new page.

Answer (score 0):

When you are waiting for element, at first you should **never** declare WebElement and then wait for it. When you declare a WebElement it should be readily available for WebDriver on browser.

Initially, you need to wait for element(declare or initialise element inside wait) in wait statement like below

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("your xpath or id")));
```

or

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("your xpath")));
```

and then declare your element here for further operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ID with `JavascriptExecutor` as alternative if wait is not working

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("formdesigner"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Can you explain me in detail like why this thing worked and not others?

Comment: sometime element is not present in dom so we have to use JavascriptExecutor  to access it directly.

Comment: Yo still have some doubt

Answer (score -2):

Try using implicit wait as shown below.

```
    WebElement w1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='formdesigner']"));
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement((By.xpath("//*[@id='formdesigner']"))).click();
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Tried, still same issue.